# Correct way of proving if and only if statements?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

When proving that
\begin{equation}
A\iff B
\end{equation}
We generally split the prof into two parts:

\begin{equation}
 A\implies B \tag{1}
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
B\implies A
\end{equation}
In the cases I have seen, these proofs are completely independent. Today I've come across a different proof, though. After proving $(1)$, it proved $(2)$ by using $(1)$ in the last part of the proof. Is it fine to do so from a logical standpoint?

Comment: Although I can't imagine a scenario in which a proof is structured like this off the top of my head, I think that it is ok. You know that (1) is true so why not use it?

Comment: I came across this in proving the zero product law for a vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is OK. After proving $A\implies B$ you can use it for whatever proof you like,
even for the proof of $B\implies A$. This does not introduce a logical flaw of some sort.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. What made me doubt was the fact that I needed to prove $(1)$ before $(2)$ doing this way. Anyways, do you also have any example of another proof where this happens?